# Where did the edit UI tab go in QGIS 2.0?

Tags: qgis

QGIS 2 looks like a big improvement in the software, but a feature I really loved seems to have either moved or been dropped.  I have been using Qt Creator to make custom forms for attribute entry, and then just linking them in through this nice simple tab in the layer properties dialog.

Does anyone know if there is a new way to do this (python???) or am I just out of luck and did all that work making forms for nothing?

Answer (score 3):

There still is. In order to get all the form styling into one single place, this was moved to the "Fields" tab. Choose "Provide ui-file" from the "Attribute editor layout" dropdown and select your UI file.

[image]

There's also a handy "Drag and Drop" method you can choose as alternative, which will probably satisfy 90% of the form design needs without having to open the QtDesigner.

Comment: fabulous!  I figured there was some simple solution.  thanks y muchas gracias!